# Accessing JSON Resource on a RESTful one page app

Tags: rest, backbone.js, laravel, single-page-application

Given a one page app that uses push state and RESTful backend, we can imagine accessing the listing of a resource at `/resourceName` (i.e. `/users`). So /users would create a formated list of users

Now the problem is that this resource JSON or XML feed should also be mapped to `/resourceName`, so if boot form my application entry point at `/` then all is good, when navigating to `/users` the JS router can trigger a Ajax call that get the JSON data. Now the problem is if the URL is pointing directly at `/users` then i will land on a JSON feed instead of the actual listing. I could route all call to a main entry point and then let the JS router do the work though if i do so the AJAX call to fetch JSON wil brake.

I remember a while ago people adding `.json` to their json request, or even a GET parameter `?format=json` and then having the controller taking different actions. I find that somewhat hacky.. Are there any other ways to go about this?

For that matter i am using laravel4 backend and backboneJS

Answer (score 1):

I think the `.json` on the end of the request is the best approach. the other approach could be to create a separate endpoint endpoint for api request `api.mydomain.com` vs `www.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 1):

What method you use to get a different response depends on how you'd like to go about it. Since you're asking about an opinionated topic (**There is no one right answer**), here's some options you can explore.

First, here's a [good read from Apigee on API design](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf), which covers what I'll write about here. See page 20 on "Support multiple formats"

1. The Rails way: Append a .json, .xml or other extension at the end of your request and handle that code within Laravel (You may want to use the "before" filter to check the request or Laravel's excellent route parameters, which allow the use of regex to define the route).
2. You can check the "accept" header in the request and set that header in your ajax calls to "application/json" instead of the default "application/html" to inform your application which format to use in its response. Again, the before or after filters may come in handy to check the request and define the response as appropriate
3. Create a query string `?format=json" or similar. Same comments as in point 1.

Laravel doesn't have built-in methods to change the response for you. You can, however, fairly easily detect what's being asked and choose which format to return in. It does take some thinking about how you want to accomplish that, however.

Some options off the top of my head:

1. Use the "before" or "after" filter to check what the request "wants" for a format, and do some transformations on the response to make that work
2. [Extend the request and response class](http://fideloper.com/extend-request-response-laravel) to "automate" this (request class to detect format, response class to transform the response to the correct format)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the input, tho i still find this a little hacky.. I am going for the multiple endpoints approach which is a breeze to implement with L4! Cheers

Comment: Great - Might be good to do a quick over view of your final solution when you come to it. I know I'll be curious to see what you do!

Answer (score 0):

1. It's valid to say which representation do you want. E.g. JSON, XML or binary, depends on what you want and which serializers have you developed.
2. You framework should support either setting of default representation or if you provide some mapping `URL` -> `method` you should be able to say which representation you are going to return - also either by default or taken within some object which represents your request.

Comment: Thanks for the input but that doesn't really answer my question about other ways to go about that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using different endpoints as suggested by @Aaron Saunders. In laravel 4 this is dumb easy to implement using group routes:

app.php:

```
'domain' => 'whatever.dev',
```

routes.php:

```
define('APP_DOMAIN', 'app.' . Config::get('app.domain'));
define('API_DOMAIN', 'api.' . Config::get('app.domain'));

Route::group(array('domain' => API_DOMAIN), function()
{
    // API ROUTES
});


Route::group(array('domain' => APP_DOMAIN), function()
{
    // VIEW ROUTES
});
```

Beautiful!